# JavaScript input validation

Tags: javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">

// at least one number, one lowercase and one uppercase letter
// at least six characters
var re = /(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{6,}/;
var validPassword = re.test(input);

</script>
```

Hi guys i have this input validation for password. However, I am not sure how do I insert an input box and a submit button which calls the check.

Currently I have a input box and submit button which will have errors if compiled.

Comment: What has this question to do with "java" or "netbeans"?

Comment: And what do you mean by "errors if compiled"? Show us your code with the input box and submit button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have HTML along the lines of the following:

```
<form action="somewhere.php" method="post" id="yourForm">
    <input type="password" id="pass" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Then you can use JavaScript such as the following:

```
document.getElementById("yourForm").onsubmit = function() {
    var re = /(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{6,}/;
    var validPassword = re.test(document.getElementById("pass").value);
    return validPassword;
}
```

This simply attaches a click event handler to the submit button, and tests the regular expression against the value of the input. If the regex matches, the form will submit as normal. If not, `false` will be returned and the form will not submit.

Here's a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/pTMsK/1/).